Electric Potential of charged conductors
I am most probably having a conceptual mistake about the 'Potential of charged conductors',
By relating the concepts I learned in gravitation and based on my intuition, I thought that charged conductors only apply an electric potential at a point that can be experienced by another test charge placed near it (I learned it by considering point charges applying a potential on another test charge within its field).. But recently I studied that the charged conductors themselves have a electric potential even if they are isolated from any other fields. Is it because a charged conductors consists of many point charges that apply potential on each other? Did I get something wrong?

The electric field arises as a result of the presence of a source. Indeed, if one has only one point charge in an otherwise completely empty space, there will exist an electric field everywhere in space and therefore an electric potential at each spatial point as well. This is a consequence of the following Maxwell equation:
$$\nabla\cdot\vec E(\vec r) = \rho (\vec r)/\epsilon_0,$$
where the scalar function $\rho(\vec r)$ is the source density; this may be one single isolated charge, or a continuous distribution of charge as the problem may specify. One can write the general formula for the potential of a single point charge at any point $\vec r^\prime$ with respect to the origin of coordinates as:
$$\phi(\vec r)= {1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}{q\over |\vec r -\vec r^\prime |}.$$


Is it because a charged conductors consists of many point charges that apply potential on each other?

Macroscopically, we can treat charged conductors (aka electrodes) as regions of distributed charge, rather than as collections of point charges. While the potential at an actual point charge is undefined (+/- infinity) this isn't true of a distributed charge.
This is because the actual point charges within the electrode are close enough together that the field they produce is indistinguishable (with macroscopic instruments) from what would be produced by distributed charges.
At the same time the charges in the electrode are (ignoring quantum mechanics and just thinking of the mobile electrons as forming an "electron gas" flowing around a lattice of positively charged nuclei) far enough apart that you can always fit another electron in there if you provide it enough energy. Which is another way of saying that we can define the potential of the electrode itself and not just the space around it.
(If we consider QM then we also find that the free electrons are not even really point particles, but have wavefunctions that are distributed over volumes bigger than individual atoms)
